# I don't agree this evaluation of the volume of $E=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ 4 \leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 9, x^2+y^2 \geq 1\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral

I've found the following solution of the problem "Evaluate the volume of $E=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ 4 \leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 9, x^2+y^2  \geq 1\}$.", but I don't agree with that from some point to the end, can someone help me understand if I'm wrong or right?

The set is even in all the three coordinates $x=r \cos t,\, y=r \sin t,\, z=z$ with $r \geq 0$ and $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$, the volume is given by $8$ times the volume of the set
$F=\{\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ 4 \leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 9, x^2+y^2  \geq 1, x \geq0,y\geq0,z\geq0\}$.

Using cylindrical coordinates, we get that $F$ becomes the set
$$G=\{(r,t,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ 4 \leq r^2+z^2 \leq 9,r^2\geq1, r\cos t \geq 0, r \sin t \geq0,z\geq0\}$$
$$=\{(r,t,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ 4-r^2 \leq z^2 \leq 9-z^2,r\geq1, 0 \leq t \leq \pi/2 ,z \geq 0\}$$
Now it is $4-r^2 \leq z^2 \leq 9-r^2 \iff \sqrt{4-r^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{9-r^2}$ with the conditions $4-r^2 \geq 0$ and $9-r^2 \geq 0$; those two conditions together and the fact that $r \geq 1$ lead to $1 \leq r \leq 2$; since it must be $z \geq 0$ and $z \geq \sqrt{4-r^2}$, being the root always nonnegative it is $z \geq \sqrt{4-r^2}$. So **in my opinion** it should be
$$\text{Volume}(E)=8\iiint_G rdrdtdz=8\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_1^2 \int_{\sqrt{4-r^2}}^{\sqrt{9-r^2}}rdzdrdt$$
However the solution uses my same reasoning except when it must be discussed the interval of integration for $z$: it says that we must split the integral in the sum of these two integrals and so **according to the solution** it should be
$$\text{Volume}(E)=8\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_1^2 \int_{\sqrt{4-r^2}}^{\sqrt{9-r^2}}rdzdrdt+8\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_2^3 \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-r^2}}rdzdrdt$$
Because it says that the conditions $4 \leq r^2+z^2 \leq 9,z\geq 0$ are equivalent to the system
$$\begin{cases} z \leq -\sqrt{4-r^2} \vee z \geq \sqrt{4-r^2} \\ -\sqrt{9-r^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{9-r^2} \\ z \geq 0\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases} z \geq \sqrt{4-r^2} \\ 0\ \leq z \leq \sqrt{9-r^2}\end{cases}$$
And it says that $\sqrt{4-r^2} \leq z \implies 4-r^2 \geq 0$ and $\sqrt{9-r^2} \geq z \implies 9-r^2 \geq 0$, so it has to split the integral in the sum of two integrals that have different intervals on $r$ because of those implications. But I don't understand this latter statement, because it is not like I'm having two different conditions from above or two different conditions from below on the variable $z$ that can vary according to the interval where $r$ belongs to, because it is always $\sqrt{4-r^2} \geq 0$ and so the two conditions $z \geq 0$ and $z \geq \sqrt{4-r^2}$ are basically the only one condition $z \geq \sqrt{4-r^2}$. Am I wrong or am I right? Thanks.

Comment: fix this $4-r^2 \leq z^2 \leq 9-z^2$

Comment: $r$ is not limited by $1$ and $2.$ I would rather use spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates you get the set of conditions
$$
4\leqslant r^2+z^2\leqslant 9,\quad r^2\geqslant 1,\quad  r\cos t\geqslant 0,\quad r\sin t\geqslant 0,\quad  z\geqslant 0\tag1
$$

However these inequalities can be simplified a lot because in cylindrical coordinates $r\geqslant 0$ ever, so we get
$$
4\leqslant r^2+z^2\leqslant 9,\quad r\geqslant 1,\quad  \cos t\geqslant 0,\quad \sin t\geqslant 0,\quad  z\geqslant 0\tag2
$$
And so
$$
4\leqslant r^2+z^2\leqslant 9,\quad  z\geqslant 0,\quad r\geqslant 1,\quad 0\leqslant t\leqslant \frac{\pi }{2}\tag3
$$
Now, the inequality $4\leqslant  z^2+r^2\leqslant 9$ is satisfied for some $z$ if and only if $r\leqslant 3$, and together with the condition $r\geqslant 1$ we have that at most the range of $r$ is $[1,3]$. When $r\in[1,2]$ we have that the first inequality in (3) gives $z\in[\sqrt{4-r^2},\sqrt{9-r^2}]$ (because $z\geqslant 0$), and when $r\in[2,3]$ the inequality $4\leqslant r^2+z^2$ is trivially true for all values of $z$ so we only must care about the inequality $r^2+z^2\leqslant  9$, then in this case the range of $z$ is $[0,\sqrt{9-r^2}]$ (again, because $z\geqslant 0$).

These conditions are exactly the same of the given answer of your book.

---

I will add a different way to see it using set theory: let the conditions
$$
4-r^2\leqslant z^2\leqslant 9-r^2,\quad z\geqslant 0,\quad r\geqslant 1
$$
Then using intervals the conditions are equivalent to
$$
z^2\in [4-r^2,9-r^2]\cap [0,\infty )=[\max\{0,4-r^2\},9-r^2]
$$
and
$$
\max\{0,4-r^2\}=\begin{cases}
0,& r>2\\
4-r^2,&r\in[1,2]
\end{cases}
$$
Finally note when $r>3$ then the interval $[\max\{0,4-r^2\},9-r^2]$ is the empty set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I see where I was  wrong, I still have a little doubt. While I understand that the root $\sqrt{4-r^2}$ is not even defined for $r \in (2,3]$, when trying to solve the system algebraically for $z$ I always end up with $0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{9-r^2}$ for $r \in [1,3]$, because of the intersection with $r \geq 1$. In other words, apart from an intuitive or geometric point of view, I don't find how the math tells me to consider $0 \leq \sqrt{9-r^2}$ for $r \in [2,3]$ instead of considering it for $r \in [1,3]$. Where this come from from mere calculations?

Comment: @Gwyn just don't take square roots, or said in other words: when you take square roots you are assuming that the values are non-negative, that is, in the inequality $-1\leqslant c\leqslant 5$ it doesnt make sense to take square roots, you only can took roots when you assume that every is non-negative. In your case, as you have the condition that $c\geqslant 0$, then an inequality of the form $-1\leqslant c\leqslant  5$ simplifies to $0\leqslant c\leqslant 5$, or using set theory, you have that $c\in[-1,5]\cap [0,\infty )=[0,5]$

Comment: @Gwyn I added a different way to handle the conditions using set theory in the answer, take a look to see if you see it more clear now

Comment: @Masacoroso: Thanks for your help, I see it clearly now from the inequalities but my problem is with how the logical "or" is treated when dealing with existence conditions of the two roots and other logical "and" conditions in the system of inequalities. My problem is that I don't know how to algebraically infer, from $[z \geq \sqrt{4-r^2} \land 1 \leq r \leq 2] \land (0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{9-r^2} \land 1 \leq r \leq 3)$, the fact that the second condition $0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{9-r^2}$ holds only for $2 \leq r \leq 3$ and not for $1 \leq r \leq 3$ (graphically is clear, I mess up the system).

Comment: @Gwyn I already show it to you with two different methods how to do it. I don't know what more I can do.